# NuGet not working properly with Asp5-Mvc6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, nuget, asp.net-core, dnx

When restoring packages in the new `xproj` project types, there are the new package config in the `project.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        ....
}
```

Nuget restores theese with no problem.

When the `.xproj` depends on normal `.proj` files, you sometimes needs to create wrappers, and write the dependency like this:

```
"frameworks": {
        "dnx46": {
            "dependencies": {
                "SomeOldProjectAssembly": "1.0.0-*"
            }
        }
    }
```

The wrapper is not important here.

When using nuget to restore packages, in this `project.json` file: `nuget restore .\project.json` the nuget packages is restored, but Nuget.exe also tries to restore the assemply dependencies.

I get this error from Nuget.exe:

```
C:\SomePlace> nuget.exe restore .\project.json
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
Restoring packages for C:\SomePlace\project.json...
  NotFound https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/escenic.net/index.json 639ms
  NotFound https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/escenic.net.configgenerator/index.json 713ms
  NotFound https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/escenic.net.base/index.json 720ms
Unable to resolve SomeOldProjectAssembly (≥ 1.0.0--) for DNX,Version=v4.6.
Exception of type 'NuGet.CommandLineException' was thrown.
```

From the specs found on nuget, the command line tool should understand the json config file: https://docs.nuget.org/Consume/ProjectJson-Intro

When using the new package restore tool `dnu`, there is no problems - it only fetches the nuget packeges and ignores the assembly dependencies.

One solution is to call `DNU` for the `project.json` files, and nuget for the old `packages.config` - but thats just not convenient.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1127

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current situation is that you need to use `dnu restore` to restore `project.json` projects and `nuget restore` for `.csproj` projects.

We are working on moving all restore logic to `nuget` though.

Comment: Sounds like the bedst idea to having it all one place :) Any idea when nuget will work fully with project.json packages?

Comment: We hope it will happen in the next release