# How to add DefinitelyTyped in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I tried using NuGet, but it's not working. Using Bower or NPM (I don't know where to use the npm commands in VS 2015, there's no GUI) didn't work either. I'm still trying to get used to the new structure ect. I guess it's normal that NuGet is not working?!

Output of NuGet:

```
Retrieving package 'jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped 3.1.1' from 'nuget.org'.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/jquery.typescript.definitelytyped/3.1.1/jquery.typescript.definitelytyped.3.1.1.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/jquery.typescript.definitelytyped/3.1.1/jquery.typescript.definitelytyped.3.1.1.nupkg 458ms
Installing jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped 3.1.1.
Installing NuGet package jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped.3.1.1.
Successfully installed 'jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped 3.1.1' to NewWebProject
Executing nuget actions took 704,97 ms
========== Finished ==========
Time Elapsed: 00:00:03.0703945
PATH=.\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\git
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe restore "C:\Users\Marcel\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NewWebProject\.vs\restore.dg"
log  : Restoring packages for C:\Users\Marcel\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NewWebProject\src\NewWebProject\project.json...
log  : Restoring packages for tool 'BundlerMinifier.Core' in C:\Users\Marcel\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NewWebProject\src\NewWebProject\project.json...
log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools' in C:\Users\Marcel\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NewWebProject\src\NewWebProject\project.json...
log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools' in C:\Users\Marcel\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NewWebProject\src\NewWebProject\project.json...
log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools' in C:\Users\Grief\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NewWebProject\src\NewWebProject\project.json...
log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools' in C:\Users\Grief\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NewWebProject\src\NewWebProject\project.json...
log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools' in C:\Users\Grief\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NewWebProject\src\NewWebProject\project.json...
log  : Writing lock file to disk. Path: C:\Users\Grief\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NewWebProject\src\NewWebProject\project.lock.json
log  : C:\Users\Grief\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NewWebProject\src\NewWebProject\NewWebProject.xproj
log  : Restore completed in 10497ms.
PATH=.\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\git
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe restore "C:\Users\Marcel\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NewWebProject\.vs\restore.dg"
log  : Restoring packages for C:\Users\Marcel\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NewWebProject\src\NewWebProject\project.json...
log  : Restoring packages for tool 'BundlerMinifier.Core' in C:\Users\Marcel\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NewWebProject\src\NewWebProject\project.json...
log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools' in C:\Users\Marcel\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NewWebProject\src\NewWebProject\project.json...
log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools' in C:\Users\Marcel\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NewWebProject\src\NewWebProject\project.json...
log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools' in C:\Users\Marcel\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NewWebProject\src\NewWebProject\project.json...
log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools' in C:\Users\Marcel\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NewWebProject\src\NewWebProject\project.json...
log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools' in C:\Users\Marcel\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NewWebProject\src\NewWebProject\project.json...
log  : Lock file has not changed. Skipping lock file write. Path: C:\Users\Marcel\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NewWebProject\src\NewWebProject\project.lock.json
log  : C:\Users\Marcel\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NewWebProject\src\NewWebProject\NewWebProject.xproj
log  : Restore completed in 10674ms.
```

EDIT:
[image: New MVC.NET Core Project]

Comment: I'm sorry but isn't DefinitelyTyped a TypeScript thing?

Comment: Yes, i am using TypeScript and want to add the D.ts for jquery

Answer (score 0):

NuGet is definitely the way.

On VS 2015 previous to update 3, I noticed that sometimes in order to use NuGet, you have to start the IDE in administrator mode.

If it does not work try cleaning MEF cache as reported [here](https://github.com/Codealike/Codealike-KnowledgeBase/blob/master/clear-visual-studio-component-cache.md), in your case:

1. Close Visual Studio (ensure devenv.exe is not present in the Task Manager)
2. Delete the %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache directory
3. Restart Visual Studio.

Comment: I tried this (I always start VS as admin) but it didn't help. I added my NuGet output to the question. No d.ts in my project :/ Guess it's because it's ment to work with "normal" MVC Projects?! No MVC Core?

Comment: If you take a look to that output, it says that NuGet failed writing on disk and then can't install the packages; apparently another user (Grief?) put a lock on your project and did not unlock it.

Comment: I see the message that the package was successfully installed. The lock you mention is lock.json maybe. After the nuget installation MVC core makes a restore for NPM, guess that's where this is coming from

Comment: It's not easy to troubleshoot your problem from here. The first idea that pops in my mind is that the typescript folder is somehow not included in project, while NuGet keeps ovewriting it. Can you please take a look to NewWebProject/packages directory and tell me if `jquery.Typescript.DefinitelyTyped.version` is there? Can you perform same check in project root/packages.config?

Comment: Hi, thanks. I added a gif of me creating a new MVC.NET MVC Core Project. There is no TS-Folder. I guess it's because it's a ASP.NET Core MVC project, not a regular MVC 5 project (Core has a complete different file structure as you can see). TS itself works, I put my scripts in the wwwroot/js folder. I guess I have to add the d.ts manually for now :/

Comment: You can try this: in your project root create a script folder and include it in your project. Here create your tsconfig which points to proper output directory. Within script folder create a new one named typings, then try again with nuget

Comment: I tried it this way. Compiling of TS files still works. I figured that NuGet is not working at all with this project type. Tried installing Newtonsoft.Json, nothing happens. The project.json gets altered, but no binaries were added. Guess it'S a bug or not meant to work this way. Only Bower and NPM support?!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33919834/nuget-not-working-properly-with-asp5-mvc6 ... guess i am right. project.json seems to be the issue